# Custom js snippets to run on any page in chrome shortcut?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, shortcut

Title may be rather poorly worded (I'll revise it if I can).

Basically, I have a few bits of jQuery and just general javascript I like to run on certain pages when I'm debugging.

Rather than starting up the console window and pasting it in there, is it there a way of storing these snippets (of which there are many) so that I can just click a button and it mimics me running it in the console window? The equivalent to a macro in VBA I suppose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a bookmark with your script as url (prepending `javascript:`):

```
javascript:yourScriptHere();
```

and click it on your favorited bar in any page.

Comment: Sorted, exactly what I was after.